# I want a minimum value in a cell only if there are values entered entered

Tags: worksheet-function, checksum

```
=MAX(150,SUM((D3+E3)*2))
```

is what I use but I don't need it to fill if values are not entered in D3 and E3

[image]

Comment: `=IF(D3<>"",MAX(150,(D3+E3)*2) ,"")`

Comment: Thank you too much